# Failing to update Yarn on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7-x64, yarnpkg, updating

I am running a **Windows7 64bit** machine and am trying to update **Yarn**.

Currently, I have version **1.0.1** and I have tried the following things in order to update it :

- npm update --global yarn
- npm install -g yarn
- yarn self-update ([which doesn't work at the moment](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/self-update/))
- I have also downloaded the .msi installer from [here](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable)

All of the above seem to finish their process, but do not actually update yarn.

In my PATH variable, I have

> C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin

yarn check produces a ton of errors [image: errors]

I searched online and in SO, but could not find an answer.

If anyone has any idea as to what I am doing wrong, or what I can do to update yarn, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What is your node version

Comment: @MoatazAhmedSamy - Node version is 8.14.0 and npm is 6.4.1

Comment: Why don’t you update both to latest stable version and try to setup yarn again

Comment: I will try to simulate your setup environment and send you my feedback

Comment: @MoatazAhmedSamy - I tried that, but it didn't work so I degraded to older versions.

Comment: i am trying now to install the node js and npm that you stated but the stable version of yarn version 1.12.3 and i will see the result and tell you ... i am interested in this question dont mind

Comment: try my solution but delete any installations and restart your pc after deleting all packages

Comment: Did you find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**installation steps**

I have installed node js 8.14.0 which include npm version 6.4.1 from this link [file name is node-v8.14.0-x64.msi](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.14.0/)     and downloaded yarn from their site the msi version the stable version 1.12.3

and yarn is finally installed ....;-) enjoy

[image: yarn installed]

Comment: Ahemd Samy - Thank you. Before your answer, I already tried unnistalling and reinstalling, but it did not work. I am still having an issue with yarn in an open source repository, but it seems that I have progressed a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try running npm or Chocolatey from an admin powershell.

`choco install yarn`
or
`choco upgrade yarn`

Comment: Yes for the choco command but I would first try running npm from an admin powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar trouble upgrading yarn on windows.

But after a couple of try I was able to upgrade yarn simply download msi file from here https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install then first select remove yarn from your computer. After removing completed open again msi this time you will see new install process just follow and install new yarn.